# Bind a lambda to a function to get return result

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, template-meta-programming, c++14

Trying to pass a lambda as a parameter to a function that takes a `std::function` then using type deduction to get the return value. But it fails to compile.

```
#include <future>


class WorkQue
{
    public:
        template<typename R, typename ...Args>
        std::future<R> addItem(std::function<R(Args...)> task, Args... args)
        {
            std::promise<R>     promise;
            std::future<R>      future = promise.get_future();

            // STUFF

            return future;
        }
};

int main()
{
    WorkQue     que;
    int         x = 1;
    int         y = 2;

    // This fails
    que.addItem([](int x, int y){return x+y;}, x, y);

    // I can see needing to specify the return type.
    // But even this does not work.
    // que.addItem<int>([](int x, int y){return x+y;}, x, y);

    // This works fine.
    // But I was hoping not to need to specify this every time.
    //que.addItem<int>(std::function<int(int,int)>([](int x, int y){return x+y;}), x, y);
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
> g++ -std=c++1y thread.cpp
thread.cpp:24:9: error: no matching member function for call to 'addItem'
    que.addItem([](int x, int y){return x+y;}, x, y);
    ~~~~^~~~~~~
thread.cpp:9:24: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-0 (type-parameter-0-1...)>' against '<lambda at thread.cpp:24:17>'
        std::future<R> addItem(std::function<R(Args...)> task, Args... args)
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Reminds me of http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/109

Comment: Type erasure or type deduction: choose one.

Comment: Also, what is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `std::function`

```
class WorkQue
{
    public:
        template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
        auto addItem(Func && task, Args &&... args) -> std::future<decltype(task(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>
        {
            using R = decltype(task(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
            std::promise<R>     promise;
            std::future<R>      future = promise.get_future();

            // STUFF

            return future;
        }
};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1a8b02a1fbf5123

Comment: It's probably best to use `Args &&...` and `decltype(std::forward<Func>(task)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`, perfectly forward everything from the call site.

Comment: @Mankarse you are right. but is it necessary to forward `task` in `decltype`?

Comment: @BryanChen I think so, otherwise the `decltype` might be ill-formed if one of the `args` cannot be copied, and you'll end up SFINAE'ing the function (but I'm not sure of this). Anyway, you could just use `result_of`.

Comment: @Bryan Chen: Not if `addItem` is only ever called with a lambda. Yes in the general case, when the `operator()` could be ref-qualified ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f762df72e21b11ce)).

Comment: @Mankarse Thanks for the example. But I think it will add too much noise in the code for little gain in this answer.